# Cast error in generated code when executing Hive.openBox()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

When I run the code below, a _CastError is thrown when the box is opened. I can post the generated code if it will help, though presumably, the error is in my source code.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'hive_playground.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Person {
  Person({required this.name, required this.age, required this.friend});

  @HiveField(0)
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  int age;

  @HiveField(2)
  Friend friend;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$name: $age';
  }
}

@HiveType(typeId: 2)
class Friend {
  Friend({required this.friendName, required this.friendAge});

  @HiveField(0)
  String friendName;

  @HiveField(1)
  int friendAge;
}

void main() async {
  var path = Directory.current.path;
  Hive
    ..init(path)
    ..registerAdapter(PersonAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter(FriendAdapter());

  var box = await Hive.openBox('testBox');

  // var dave = Friend(friendName: 'Dave', friendAge: 22);

  // var person = Person(name: 'Harry', age: 23, friend: dave);

  // await box.put('Harry', person);

  // print(box.get('Harry')); // Dave: 22
}
```

This is the error message thrown when attempting to open the box.

```
_CastError (type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'Friend' in type cast)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if order matters, but consider registering FriendAdapter before PersonAdapter. Also, did you save/retrieve any data before completely defining all the adapters? There might be old data in the cache that doesn't match the current adapter definition or stuff. So you may want to clear Hive and start again let's see.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Friend` and `Person` classes should extend `HiveObject`, [as per the docs](https://pub.dev/packages/hive#store-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Because the old invalid data still existed in box.

Try:

```
Hive.deleteBoxFromDisk("accounts");
await Hive.openBox("accounts");
```

to remove box.